# Cannot update app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

When installing the latest version of the iOS app it fails telling it can't download the update. It happens at approximately 75% in the loading phase.

I have tried it on various networks and have done a lot of attempts already.

Is this a deployment bug?

**Update:**

It seems to be a deployment bug indeed since the update is retracted now and can't be downloaded any more. The app doesn't show an update too.

---

- App Version: 1.3.2.231
- Device: iPhone7,2
- OS Version: Version 9.0 (Build 13A344)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in 1.4.0.234.

Back when iOS8 came out there was a bug with users updating to the new build and the solution was to make iOS think it was downloading a different app than it actually was, up until the point it installed.  That is, it downloaded as `com.stackexchange.ent.zaphod.ios8fix` but then installed as `com.stackexchange.ent.zaphod`.  That's why updates would always appear as a new download.

iOS9 is now rejecting this hack at validation time:

> itunesstored[143] : BundleValidator: Failed bundleIdentifier: com.stackexchange.ent.zaphod.ios8fix does not match expected bundleIdentifier: com.stackexchange.ent.zaphod

So, I'm removing the hack, things are downloading in the right spot, and hopefully we don't run into any more problems like this in the future.