# Unable to install beta app in iOS 9.1 beta 1

Tags: bug, ios-app

Whether you have the app installed or not, trying to install a new version fails. It reaches 100% but then an alert pops up stating that the app could not be installed at this time.

The profile appears to be valid, so I'm not sure why it fails...
Too bad I was tempted to check if this also happens if you remove the app... meh.

Comment: [Is this the same issue I reported an hour ago?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266528/245360)

Comment: So it happens on 9.0 as well?  Looks very similar, yes.

Comment: Yes, it does. Maybe a general deployment failure?

Comment: @idar see my post for Brian's answer.